# error 9 Bad file descriptor error using sockets in python

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, server

I am trying to implement a very basic code of client server in python using non blocking sockets. I have made two threads for reading and writing.

My client code is below.

```
import sys
import socket
from time import sleep
from _thread import *
import threading

global s

def writeThread():
    while True:
        data = str(input('Please input the data you want to send to client 2 ( to end connection type end ) : '))
        data = bytes(data, 'utf8')
        print('You are trying to send : ', data)
        s.sendall(data)

def readThread():
    while True:
        try:
            msg = s.recv(4096)
        except socket.timeout as e:
            sleep(1)
            print('recv timed out, retry later')
            continue
        except socket.error as e:
           # Something else happened, handle error, exit, etc.
            print(e)
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            if len(msg) == 0:
                print('orderly shutdown on server end')
                sys.exit(0)
            else:
                # got a message do something :)
                print('Message is : ', msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    global s
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('',6188))
    s.settimeout(2)

    wThread = threading.Thread(None,writeThread)
    rThread = threading.Thread(None,readThread)

    wThread.start()
    rThread.start()

    s.close()
```

**Question:**

I know this can be implemented through select module too but I would like to know how to do it this way.

Comment: It will help if you provide the exact error output.

Comment: does the connect call succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Your main thread creates the socket, then creates thread1 and thread2. Then it *closes* the socket (and exits because the program ends after that). So that when thread1 and thread2 try to use it, it's no longer open. Hence `EBADF` (Bad file descriptor error).

Your main thread should not close the socket while the other threads are still running. It could wait for them to end:

```
[...]
s.settimeout(2)
wThread = threading.Thread(None,writeThread)
rThread = threading.Thread(None,readThread)
wThread.start()
rThread.start()
wThread.join()
rThread.join()
s.close()
```

However, since the main thread has nothing better to do than wait, it might be better to create only one additional thread (say `rThread`), then have the main thread take over the task currently being performed by the other.  I.e.

```
[...]
s.settimeout(2)
rThread = threading.Thread(None,readThread)
rThread.start()
writeThread()
```